# charts js chart getting vanished inside bootstrap accordion panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, charts, accordion

I have a strange issue regarding displaying chartsjs canvas element inside bootstrap accordion. Scenario is I have to display 6 types of charts as 3*2(Grid view) in desktop mode and as 6 rows(inside bootstrap accordion panels) in mobile view.Im trying with two div elements one for mobile and other for desktop and writing media queries to display accordion only on mobile view but normal grid view on desktop mode.I dont see any issues with desktop mode,but on mobile view for the first time all the charts are rendered properly but on multiple clicks on all the 6 charts im seeing that chart is getting vanished.Can you please help me out with this.

//For mobile view

```
//html code

<div id="mobileRadarView">
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panelOne">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
  <h4 class="panel-title" >
      Chart1
    <a id="chart1Collapse" class="collapsed"  style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;float:right" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"><span style="color:white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <canvas id="chart1" height="400" width="600"></canvas> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>

//Javascript code

 var data = {
            labels: ["X","Y","Z"],
        datasets: [
        {
        label: "DATASET1",
        fillColor: "rgba(63,169,245,.1)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(63,169,245,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#FA8585",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)", 
        data: [10,20,30]
        },
        {
            label: "DATASET2",
             fillColor: "rgba(255,196,203,.1)",
             strokeColor: "rgba(255,196,203,1)",
             pointColor: "rgba(243,101,117,1)",
             pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
             pointHighlightFill: "#FA8585",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)", 
            data: [40,50,60]    
        },
        {
            label: "DATASET3",
            fillColor: "rgba(156,250,179,.1)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(77,246,119,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(52,245,100,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#FA8585",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)", 
            data: [35,50,70]    
        }
        ]
        };
        var options={responsive: true,maintainAspectRatio: true};

 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.panel#panelOne').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
           var mobileRadarChart=document.getElementById('chart1').getContext('2d');
          new Chart(mobileRadarChart).Radar(data,options); 
         })
        });
```

//For desktop view

```
//html code

<div id="desktopRadarView">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
     <canvas id="chart2" ></canvas>
 </div>
</div>

//Javascript code
  //data same as shown in above mobile view code
 var desktopRadarChart = document.getElementById('chart2').getContext('2d');        
        new Chart(desktopRadarChart).Radar(data,options);
```